# Server remote management solution with hardware reset and VGA output

Tags: kvm, remote-control, vga

I want to be able to manage my home server remotely and be able to turn it on/off at the hardware level (in case it hangs), preferably with the ability to see VGA output.

I was looking at something like the [Peppercon eRIC Express card](https://www.kvmchoice.com/detail_switch.asp?id=1234) but it isn't being manufactured anymore and I wanted to go for a more modern solution.

KVM over IP seems like a popular option, so I wanted to either get recommendations on a particular solution or any alternatives.

My system is on PC Part Picker [here](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/MdN8Bb).

Comment: You should change your motherboard to one intended for a server. Enterprise boards with [Intel vPro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_vPro) or [IPMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) provide remote management. AFAIK, IPMI *includes* KVM over IP built right into the board, which is why the card you are looking for is obsolete.

Comment: I did suspect this, it would quite a pain to switch the motherboard out as have just put the server together (fairly new to this) so was hoping for some alternative solution - I will go for swapping out the motherboard though if I can't find anything